# In sql how do you print only the most occuring

Tags: sql, oracle

```
   SELECT  S.CUSTID, C.NAME, COUNT(S.CUSTID) as "Customer with most Purchases"
   FROM CUSTOMER C, SALESTRANSACTION S
   WHERE C.CUSTID = S.CUSTID
   GROUP BY (S.CUSTID, C.NAME, C.CUSTID) 
   ORDER BY COUNT(S.CUSTID) DESC;
```

This actually tells us which person made the most purchases. But how can i print only the top row and not have all the other rows below?

Comment: Try add `LIMIT 1`;

Comment: add a ```LIMIT 1``` at the end of the query

Comment: it did not work. it returns an error.

Comment: its for oracle apex

Comment: I've added the `oracle` tag to your request. It is very important to tag your request with your DBMS when asking SQL questions. `LIMIT` works for several DBMS. Others want `TOP`. In standard SQL it's `FETCH FIRST`, and this is what we use in Oracle, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to fetch the highest ranked row(s) of your intermediate result. If you want to keep your query as is and only add the appropriate clause, use `FETCH` and a modified `ORDER BY` clause with `RANK` for this.

```
SELECT
  c.custid,
  c.name,
  COUNT(s.custid) AS transaction_count
FROM customer c
LEFT OUTER JOIN salestransaction s ON s.custid = c.custid
GROUP BY c.custid, c.name
ORDER BY RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(s.custid) DESC)
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

I've changed your comma separated join - a syntax that was used thirty years ago -  to a proper explicit join.

Comment: Nice observation, I didn't know [that](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6): "If you do not specify *rowcount* or *percent `PERCENT`*, then 1 row is returned." I always used `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES`